# How to add DataGridView control using VS2015?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am totally new to programming in c# and have no previous experience with Object Oriented programming. I am teaching myself, so please I have many questions. I created a simple `array` that takes information from (STEP Text file) and displays it in a `TextBox`, now I am trying to put this information in `Grid` (like table) instead of showing them in a `TextBox`. I found `Grid` and `Datagrid` in the `Toolbox` window, but couldn't find `DataGridView`. I am using `Visual Studio 2015`. I would like to know:

1. How can I add `DataGridView` to my project?
2. Is there a simple code to put the information in a `grid`?

Since I am a beginner, please, be patient with me.

Comment: `ListView` is a very common way to construct a grid in WPF. Most people just write the xaml. There are plenty of Google-able examples, [this site](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/) is usually very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `DataGridView` is `Windows Forms` control and is available in `Windows Forms` project type only. You wont be able to use that in your `WPF` project. The equivalent in `WPF` is `DataGrid`.

As for the part regarding adding information in a grid, you will have to set the `DataContext` property of the `DataGrid`. For learning `WPF`, I would recommend to check out the two websites below:
https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDataGrid.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I found codes for DataGrideView, but not for DataView, what do you advise me?

Comment: If you found code for DataGridView, then you must be looking at WinForms tutorial, not WPF. I've listed two websites that I found helpful when learning WPF myself. Hope that helps.